# Extend Double only within my struct

Tags: swift, protocols

I'd like to be able to extend `Double` with a custom conversion to `String`, but I would like to limit this only to implementations with classes/structs.  For

```
extension Double {
  var customStringOutput: String {
    guard self >= 0.0 else { return "Invalid" }
    return "My number is: \(self)"
  }
}

struct MyStruct {
  var myNumber: Double = 100.0
}

let myStruct = MyStruct()
let doubleFail = 99.0
print(myStruct.myNumber.customStringOutput)    //"My number is: 100.0"
print(doubleFail.customStringOutput)           //"My number is :99.0" - Should fail
```

I have tried to create a protocol such as:

```
protocol DoubleCustomStringConvertable { ... }
```

Applying that to `Double` produces the same result as just extending Double directly.  I can create a function within my struct that takes the double as a parameter and returns my string which would *technically* solve my problem, but this is more of a learning exercise and I like the cleaner syntax of the property.

How do I allow the protocol to only apply to Double's within my defined struct?  This is probably so simple I will kick myself!

Comment: Have you considered a private extension on Double?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it a protocol, but rather just a function defined within your structure. There is no way to limit the scope of a protocol (to all `Double`s within a value type like `MyStruct`).

Comment: As I mentioned, I could do that, but then I'm duplicating code in the different structures that need that definition.   I could put the function in a protocol and apply to the structs that need it, but I also like the syntax of double.parameter rather than func(double) - although they may be functionally equivalent.  (Code completion), limiting to certain doubles, etc...